# have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? AND password=?'

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

Thank for visiting my question :D
im trying to finish my project and i having a problem with sql.
this is my code and i dont know why and dont know to fix it.
I use java ee - Eclip to do this. (i create JSP website )

```
try{                     
    String sql = "SELECT User_Name, Password, Gender FROM User_Account WHERE User_Name=? AND password=? ";
    PreparedStatement pstm= conz.prepareStatement(sql);                 
    ResultSet rs=pstm.executeQuery(sql);         
    String user_name=null;
    String pass_word=null;

    while(rs.next()){
        user_name=rs.getString(1);
        pass_word=rs.getString(2);

         }

if(user_name.equals(userName)&&pass_word.equals(password)){
    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/userInfo");
    hasError = true;
    errorString = "Connected ";
} else {               
    hasError = true;
    errorString = "Wrong user or pass!"              
}
```

when run it appears a notification "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? AND password=?' at line 1"
help me to fix it pls.
Thank in advance.

Comment: what is your user name and password ? based on it you will get All Row from DB, please replace ? by proper value

Comment: Set the values for ? (User_Name, password) in your preparedstatement

Comment: Thanks for helping me . I fixed that problem but i dont know what's this ?Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Answer (score 2):

If you set the `?` markers you have to fill them:

```
String sql = "SELECT User_Name, Password, Gender FROM User_Account WHERE User_Name=? AND password=? ";
PreparedStatement pstm= conz.prepareStatement(sql); 
pstm.setString(1,"John Doe");
pstm.setString(2,"12345");
ResultSet rs=pstm.executeQuery();
```

do that and your SQL syntax will be correct.

Comment: Thanks, i follow ur tutorial but then i have new problem like this.Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0). And i dont know why, can you help me?

Comment: try getString("user_name") and getString("password")